# Where does rpi-imager write Wifi information?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, raspberry-pi-imager

I tried the rpi-imager tool for the first time to write RPiOS to an SD card. I've always just used `dd` and then manually edited the `cmdline` and `config` files in `boot/`. I entered my WiFi information in the GUI and wrote to the SD card, stuck it in and the RPi came online and connected to my network, but I want to know where the rpi-imager GUI writes the WiFi information.

It's not where I expect:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

but the Pi is definitely online and connected to my network!

Comment: I believe it changed in Bookworm as it uses Network Manager.

Comment: You should read https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Comment: This may be where NetworkManager (which is 10 years old and well documented) saves its connections but it is NOT put there by rpi-imager (because it can't). If you look at the boot sector (before 1st boot) you will see a file which is installed by a task that runs on boot.

Comment: @Milliways the article you posted above says the exact opposite

Comment: The article says no such thing. If you ACTUALLY looked at the image created by rpi-imager (before 1st boot) you will see how it works and it **DEFINITELY does not configure wpa_supplicant.conf**  which is what you originally asked. The OS has code (automatically run on first boot) to configure many things. [How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145593/how-do-i-set-up-networking-on-raspberry-pi-os-bookworm) explains Bookworm settings. As I stated the imager is incapable for modifying an ext4 partition.