# How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

Most of the existing networking tutorials are out of date and won't work on `Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to setup Raspberry Pi OS Networking

In [Bookworm](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/) `NetworkManager` is the default networking configuration tool.

There is *Raspberry Pi Ltd.* documentation on [Configuring Networking](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-networking)
This explains the common basic settings, but does not explain in detail advanced settings.

> If you are using an **Ethernet** connection with a router there should be no configuration required and it should work out of the box.
> The Pi3B+, Pi4 and Pi5 have **Gigabit Ethernet** interfaces and will only work on a Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) router if a 8 wire CAT 5E cable is used. Earlier Pi models which only supported 100BASE-T work over 6 wire cable.

If you **preconfigure** during the imaging process you can set the *hostname*, *user/password*, *Locale*, wireless networking and enable *ssh* and is recommended.

The rest of this tutorial is an introduction to manual configuration (particularly wireless networking) and advanced settings.

> This is a work in progress and currently only describes a limited subset of `NetworkManager` capabilities. `NetworkManager` has been in use in other OS for many years and there are many on line tutorials.

### General

Each WiFi network has a separate config file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` in a well configured system these will have a 256bit WPA PSK rather than an ASCII passphrase.

### Using the Desktop

Open the networking menu on the taskbar.
This should show any Ethernet connection and available WiFi networks.

An additional sub-menu at the bottom, **Advanced Options** allows you to

- Connect to a Hidden Wi-Fi Network
- Create WiFi Hotspot
- Add a VPN connection
- Connection Information
- Edit Connection

The **Edit Connection** menu will show available connections
Select a connection and use the **+**, **-** or **⚙︎** button to Add, Delete or Edit

```
The ⚙︎ will bring up another menu and the IPv4 or IPv6 lets you select a Method
    Automatic(DHCP) 
    Automatic(DHCP) addresses only
    Manual  allows static
    Link-Local only
    Shared to other computers
    Disabled
    
    The Routes
```

### Using the Command Line

There is a `nmtui` program which presents a Curses menu with a simplified menu (which operates like `raspi-config`).

NetworkManager TUI (Text User Interface)

- Edit a connection
- Activate a connection
- Set system hostname

---

You can use the `nmcli` command to manage NetworkManager from the command line e.g.

`nmcli dev wifi list` will scan for wireless networks.
`sudo nmcli --ask dev wifi connect ssid` will connect to a network
`nmcli connection show` shows existing connections
`sudo nmcli connection modify [id | uuid | path] ipv4.route-metric nnn` will change the route metric

There are more examples in [Using the Command Line](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#wireless-networking-command-line)

### Prevent `networkmanager` from configuring a gateway on an interface

If you want an interface to not install any default routes (often used for local devices) specify

```
sudo nmcli connection modify connection_name ipv4.never-default yes ipv6.never-default yes
```

Comment: Nice summary and needed with the switch to Network Manager.  I suggest adding Cat 6 to your Cat 5E note.  Cat 6 is now commonly available at similar prices.  Also, since command line changes can disappear across a boot, please add a sentence about the persistence of changes made with nmtui and nmcli.