# Setting Metric on Bookworm

Tags: networking, networkmanager, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running bookworm.

It has a cellular modem attached via USB (interface usb0)and a Wireless connection (interface wlan0).

The usb0 has a metric of 100 and the wlan0 a metric of 600. It appears because the usb0 has a lower metric I can not connect over LAN (wlan0) connection when the modem is active.

Guide I found talked about editing the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` - but this file does not exist on newer versions of Rpi OS.

How can I set the wlan0 to have a lower metric?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145593/how-do-i-set-up-networking-on-raspberry-pi-os-bookworm)

Comment: I tried `nmcli connection usb0 down` as a test - but it doesnt like the way I am putting the device in there despite what I see on the internet

Comment: I can't find anything on routes either

Comment: How do you run nmcli in interactive? Where is the Metric in Route in the GUI? I looked.

Comment: To see what connections you've got use `nmcli con show` it will give you the names (`usb0` is a device name). To see IPv4 and IPv6 addresses use `ip a show`. To see routes use `ip r show`. To set a metric to 300 use `nmcli con modify <connection-name> ipv4.route-metric 300`. With an appropriate modification to <connection-name>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `nmcli connection edit WiFi…` puts you in interactive mode.

`nmcli connection show` will show you existing connections & what it chooses to call them (which is not standardised) e.g. if you preconfigure on the imager it is called `preconfigured`.

Under the networking icon select network `Advanced Options` `Edit Connection`  `⚙︎`, `IPv4 Settings`, `Routes` has an option to `Add` metric (you might want to ignore automatically obtained routes)

You can edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WiFi….nmconnection` but I have not tried setting metric there and defaults are not shown.

I didn't say it was easy! `NetworkManager` can do practically anything BUT finding the right incantation is a bit hit & miss and I am still learning.

You can, of course select `dhcpcd` instead.

---

I have tried `sudo nmcli connection modify 'WiFi…' ipv4.route-metric 50` which appears to work.

This sets in .nmconnection

```
[ipv4]
method=auto
route-metric=50
```