# Where is my WiFi configuration configured in Raspberry Pi Imager?

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-4

I can't find WiFi configuration that I entered during Raspbian installation.
I have fresh Raspberry Pi 4 with default Raspbian x64 system installed on SD card by using Raspberry Pi Imager 1.8.4.

During installation I have entered my user, password and WiFi configuration, enabled SSH and regional options.

My Pi connects to that network, however my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file contains only this:

```
$ sudo cat wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

There is no network.

I also have no `/etc/NetworkManager` directory.

Questions:

1. What is going on? Is this network configuration only for first boot?
2. I want to use multiple networks (phone hotspot first, and home network if hotspot is not available during boot). Should I just configure it in my `wpa_supplicant.conf`? I'm worried that initial configuration will still exist somewhere.

Comment: As I understand it, the wpa_supplicant.conf file isn't used anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145593/how-do-i-set-up-networking-on-raspberry-pi-os-bookworm)

Comment: Please specify which **release** you are using: `bookworm`, `bullseye`, `buster`???

Answer (score 0):

Starting in the `bookworm` release of raspbian, the [*purveyors*](https://www.raspberrypi.com/) have designated a new "NetworkManager" that replaces the familiar `dhcpcd`. While NetworkManager uses `wpa_supplicant`, the settings are [stored elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497540/where-is-my-wpa-supplicant-conf).

However, you **should have** a folder named `/etc/NetworkManager`; double-check that.

Assuming you find that folder, you can see what little information is available in this folder: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

On my system, I have to do this to see the only file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`:

```
sudo less /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Mesh01.nmconnection
```

As far as using multiple networks, and other configuration changes, you will need to consult `man nmcli` (or use the GUI apparatus if you're into that). There's also a [WiFi wiki for NetworkManager](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#NetworkManager) available on the Debian website that's helpful.

Comment: networkmanager DOES use wpa_supplicant as `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` will show. I just doesn't store its settings in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`