# hostapd running but wlan0 state down

Tags: hostapd, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, nginx

I try to use my pi (Raspberry Pi 4, Model B, running latest Raspberry Pi OS bookworm) as a WLAN Access Point which also provides a website.

I installed and configured hostapd, dnsmasq, dhcpcd & nginix.

It all worked out and i was able to access the wifi and then my webservice.

After a Reboot, the WLAN was not available anymore.

The AP is not discoverable by other Devices via Wifi and when i try to add/access it manually it also does not work.

I can still connect via SSH if i am in the same network (connected via cable) and then access teh website as well.

When i check the servies, they all seem fine:

```
● hostapd.service - Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-05 11:47:51 CET; 7min ago
       Docs: man:hostapd(8)
    Process: 716 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (cod>
   Main PID: 742 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8741)
        CPU: 57ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
             └─742 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Mar 05 11:47:50 rennleitung systemd[1]: Starting hostapd.service - Access point and authentication s>
Mar 05 11:47:50 rennleitung hostapd[716]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung hostapd[716]: wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung hostapd[716]: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung systemd[1]: Started hostapd.service - Access point and authentication se>
```

```
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-05 11:47:51 CET; 7min ago
    Process: 715 ExecStartPre=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq checkconfig (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 735 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 747 ExecStartPost=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-start-resolvconf (code=exited, status=0/S>
   Main PID: 746 (dnsmasq)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8741)
        CPU: 128ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
             └─746 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg->

Mar 05 11:47:50 rennleitung systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and >
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung dnsmasq[746]: started, version 2.89 cachesize 150
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung dnsmasq[746]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-UBus i18n ID>
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung dnsmasq-dhcp[746]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.1.100 -- 192.168.1.200, lease >
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung dnsmasq[746]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.conf, will retry
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung dnsmasq[746]: read /etc/hosts - 7 names
Mar 05 11:47:51 rennleitung systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and c>
Mar 05 11:47:56 rennleitung dnsmasq[746]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Mar 05 11:47:56 rennleitung dnsmasq[746]: using nameserver 192.168.178.1#53
```

The only issue i can see is that wlan0 is down, but i do not know why, or how to fix this

```
$ ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:46:e7:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:46:e7:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

For Reference, those are my config files:

`/etc/default/hostapd`:

```
RUN_DAEMON=yes
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=myAP
channel=1
hw_mode=g
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211d=1
country_code=DE
wmm_enabled=1
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=*******
```

`/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant

duid
persistent
vendorclassid
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
option host_name
option rapid_commit
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
```

Comment: What Pi? What OS? Don't expect anyone to translate a foreign language tutorial to work out WHAT YOU DID - explain.

Comment: @Milliways you're absolutely right. Sorry. I added more information now.

Comment: Have you disabled NetworkManager and enabled dhcpcd? By default Bookworm uses NetworkManager which includes AP functionality and should be simpler to setup (no additional software required). See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/145593/8697

Comment: @Milliways That was it? If you write that as an Answer i would mark it as accepted. Otherwise i'll write the Answer.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which suggestion - disabling network manager (not recommended) or using it to create a hotspot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Bookworm uses NetworkManager

If you want to use `dhcpcd` you should enable this in `raspi-confug`.

NetworkManager is the new *Raspberry Pi OS* default network manager (and is used by most Linux distros)

NetworkManager includes AP functionality and is simpler to setup (no additional software required). See [How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145593/how-do-i-set-up-networking-on-raspberry-pi-os-bookworm)

`sudo nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid 'RaspberryPiNet' password '…'` will setup a basic hotspot but it can be done through the GUI menu and additional configuration is possible.