# Raspberry Pi 3: Static IP not getting set to what I want

Tags: wifi, ethernet, static-ip

One of my PC machines is conflicting with my raspberry pi because they're sharing the same local IP.

Editing the PC's static IP is not an option, lots of hard-coded things set to this IP.

I've set both the Pi's eth0 and wlan0 interfaces to static ip 192.168.1.22:

**/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:**

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.22/24
static routers=2001:520:ff02:12b::68
static domain_name_servers=2001:520:ff02:12b::68

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.20/24
static routers=2001:520:ff02:12b::68
static domain_name_servers=2001:520:ff02:12b::68
```

PC uses 192.168.1.21

Pi should be using 192.168.1.22, but its wlan0 interface keeps getting set to 192.168.1.21:

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0 proto dhcp src **192.168.1.22** metric 100
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src **192.168.1.21** metric 600
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I set the Pi's ethernet and wifi static IP addresses to 192.168.1.22?

**EDIT:** I changed the wlan0 static ip to 192.168.1.20 but it's still using 192.168.1.21...

**EDIT 2:**
Script output:

```
[36m- Networking System
(B[0mNetworkManager active
networking active
[36m- IP addresses & routes
(B[0m1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:65:3e:78 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.22/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 79734sec preferred_lft 79734sec
    inet6 2001:569:5b0c:d500:3300:2bb5:7d7d:821c/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 14595sec preferred_lft 14295sec
    inet6 fe80::d3ac:38:75b1:c922/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:30:6b:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.21/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 79740sec preferred_lft 79740sec
    inet6 2001:569:5b0c:d500:cb03:8354:c6bf:104b/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 14595sec preferred_lft 14295sec
    inet6 fe80::37b5:9170:5012:e133/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.22 metric 100 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.21 metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.22 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.21 metric 600 
[36m- Network Devices
(B[0meth0
lo
wlan0
[36m- Connected WiFi
(B[0mPromotedNetwork
[36m- Available WiFi connections
(B[0mPromotedNetwork
PromotedNetwork
```

Comment: You can't assign the same IP address to two interfaces.

Comment: @user68186 even if I set the wlan0 static IP to a different IP, it's still being set to 192.168.1.21 for some reason.

Comment: Copy and paste the script given by @Milliways into a text editor. Save the file as `letsfindout`. Make the file executable with the command: `chmod +x letsfindout`. Then at the terminal enter the command `./letsfindout`. Note the dot and slash before the file name. This will generate some output. Copy the generated output from the terminal and paste it directly [into your question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/147275/edit) and format it as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: I've updated the question with the script output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign the same address to 2 interfaces (unless you use a bridge - in which case you assign the IP to the bridge).

Setting a static IP address is a Pi disease, rarely necessary on a network with a DHCP server. If you have some reason reserve in your router.

---

Try running the following to find out what you actually have

```
#! /bin/sh
# This script prints useful diagnostics for common Pi networking systems

# Function to print coloured headings
#  delete "tput" lines for plain output
print_head () {
 tput setaf 6
 echo $1
 tput sgr 0
}

checkactive () {
if [ $(systemctl is-active $1) = 'active' ]; then
    echo $1 'active'
fi
}

print_head "- Networking System"
# Check status of networking system
checkactive 'systemd-networkd'
checkactive 'dhcpcd'
checkactive 'NetworkManager'
checkactive 'networking'

print_head "- IP addresses & routes"
# Print IP addresses & routes
ip a
echo
ip r

print_head "- Network Devices"
ls /sys/class/net   # network devices

print_head "- Connected WiFi"
# Get SSID of connected WiFi (WRONG if AP!)
if [ -e /sys/class/net/wlan0 ]; then
    if [ $(systemctl is-active 'NetworkManager') = 'active' ]; then
        nmcli connection show |  awk '/wlan0/ {print $1}'
    else
        wpa_cli -i wlan0 status | grep -w ssid | awk -F'[=]' '{print $2}'
    fi
fi

print_head "- Available WiFi connections"
if [ -e /sys/class/net/wlan0 ]; then
    if [ $(systemctl is-active 'NetworkManager') = 'active' ]; then
        nmcli connection show |  awk '/wifi/ {print $1}'
    else
        wpa_cli list_networks | awk '/any/ {print $2}'
    fi
fi
```

---

You are using **NetworkManager** so anything you put in other config files is irrelevant. What you put in dhclient.conf actually looks like a `dhcpcd` configuration file and certainly doesn't belong there and would't set an IP address (even if it was used).

See [How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145593/how-do-i-set-up-networking-on-raspberry-pi-os-bookworm)

Comment: My router does not have this setting unfortunately.

Setting the wlan0 static IP address to another ip (say 192.168.1.20) still yields the same result: 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0 proto dhcp src **192.168.1.22** metric 100
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src **192.168.1.21** metric 600

It for some reason wants to hang on to 192.168.1.21 for some reason. Can't figure out why.

Comment: This is the only file I've edited to attempt to assign a static IP to my raspberry pi. I want my raspberry pi to have the static IP (ethernet) of 192.168.1.22 and the wlan0 of 192.168.1.20

Using command systemctl dhcpcd gives me this error: "Unknown command verb dhcpcd."

Can't find a solution on how to assign the static ip other than this file..

Comment: As I said the original command you gave me gave an error, I'm new to linux. This is the output for the command: "Unit dhcpcd.service could not be found.". If you want some kind of diagnostic you're going to have to provide me a command that outputs that because I don't know what command to issue to do that.

Comment: Updated question with your recent script

Comment: Thank you, I looked up the documentation and set the static IP through NetworkManager instead.